# nvidia driver conflict with another display adapter

Tags: drivers, nvidia-graphics-card, tablet

I have a laptop equipped with GT540M. Drivers are fine, games are running properly. But then, when I install my tablet driver (Yiynova DP10HD, just like a cheap replacement of Wacom Cintiq) which is using DisplayLink display adapter, most games won't run. The errors mostly point to directX problem (sorry if I'm mistaken), for example :

1. Dishonored : http://puu.sh/1d643
2. Resident Evil 6 :
   https://anonfiles.com/file/333db7f243176582e86cfde91f858163

Uninstalling DisplayLink adapter will of course, resolve the issue but this is the point of why Im asking: **is there's any way to run games properly without having to uninstall tablet drivers**? Additional info:

1. The tablet's display adapter is not listed on device manager unless
   I plug the tablet in.
2. The DisplayLink software only active if I plug the tablet.
3. The problem still exist even though I'm not plugging in my tablet.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: After some reading on several posts, the problem is that changes made by nvidia drivers must be catch up by updates in displaylink drivers, which means, wait for displaylink for updates for fix. These posts here http://www.displaylink.org/forum/showthread.php?t=2198 and http://plugable.com/2010/11/15/displaylink-and-nvidia-driver-compatibility-update shows that earlier nvidia drivers has no such conflict. But driver 258.96 is too old that my GPU is not even supported. So **for now**, If I want to do gaming, I have to disable displaylink service and reactivate it again if using the tablet..

Comment: I think it has something to do with the age of the chip in your device. Mine are DL-125 chips which are really old first-gen items. Because of their age, they probably have something to do with this issue.